# how to update all background images in a custom view class

Tags: android, class, android-custom-view

I have a custom view class called Avatar.  Is it possible to write a static function that when it is called it changes all current objects from that class to have a specific picture?

Here is my Avatar class

```
public class Avatar extends RoundedImageView {

private static String avatarURL;
private Context context;

public Avatar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public Avatar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public Avatar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

private void init(){
    Picasso.with(context).load(avatarURL).into(this);
}

public static void updatePicture(String url){
    avatarURL = url;
    //update all avatars
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need instance of Avatar object to update the picture. One way to that will be storing all instances of it in a List.

In your App class,

```
public static List<Avatar> avatarList = new ArrayList();
```

In yout init method of Avatar class :

```
private void init(){
    App.avatarList.add(this);
    Picasso.with(context).load(avatarURL).into(this);
}
```

Now you need to remove these views from your list as well, you can probably do that inside finalize like this :

```
@Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        App.avatarList.remove(this);
    }
```

Now to change picture in every Avatar object, iterate through the list, and call update method.

Comment: I made the class hold the object array because i think thats better.  It is working, but i am not a huge fan of it so hoping someone will come up with something better.  But thanks.

Comment: Keeping instances of your view objects outside scope is never a good idea. So I agree with you totally. But I could come up with this only.